# Is it possible, practically, to sample any point on 0 to 1 under Uniform sampling?

Tags: sampling, uniform-distribution

I am solving optimization problems where I am trying to find the minimum of a function over some sample space $\mathcal{X}$, i.e., $\min\,f(x):x\in\mathcal{X}$. Now the optimization algorithm I am using is based on trial points $x'$ which are sampled from $\mathcal{X}$.  For sake of argument, let's say $\mathcal{X}\in[0,1]$ is the unit interval.

Now I have been solving some problems where the solution lies along the boundary, i.e., $x=0$ or $x=1$ could be the solution to the minimization problem.  Now, the way I have been picking my potential solutions (trial points) is to sample $x'$ from a Uniform(0,1) distribution.

No, what my question really is, is whether or not I will ever sample 0 or 1 from that Uniform distribution.  From a practical point of view I don't think it will occur, however, from a theoretical point of view I am also not sure.  Because isn't the probability of sample any one single number from a continuous distribution equal to exactly 0? Or is there some positive probability that I will sample the endpoints of the interval?

However, running some `R` code sampling from a Uniform(0,1) distribution 100,000,000 times I am able to sample 1, but not 0 (well maybe in machine precision it is?)

```
> x = runif(100000000)
> min(x)
[1] 2.142042e-08
> max(x)
[1] 1
>
```

Comment: The definition of "continuous distribution" is that there will not be positive probability of sampling any given value.  You can even specify certain *infinite* sets of values and they will still have zero probability.  BTW, what is the output of `1-max(x)`?

Comment: You're right, it is non-zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using R's `runif` *by design* you won't be able to sample neither 0, nor 1. Check it's [source code](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/nmath/runif.c):

```
double u;
    /* This is true of all builtin generators, but protect against
       user-supplied ones */
    do {u = unif_rand();} while (u <= 0 || u >= 1);
return a + (b - a) * u;
```

Comment: That is not true though.  Above in my question I sampled 100,000,000 uniform random variables and I do sample 1 (you can see that max(x)=1).

Comment: @RustyStatistician I doubt it. That's probably a matter of how to represent the float to your console.